# Switching multiple images in image control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, wpf-controls, custom-controls

I am trying to create a custom image control  in WPF, it will have 3 states

1. Single Static Image
2. Loader Animation
3. And mouseover effect with multiple images animation

This Control will display an image, but on mouseover it will check if it has multiple images or single image. So there will be two mouseover cases

1. Single image = > nothing happens.
2. Multiple images = > it will start animating through all the images in the source

We can have change image on mouseover with trigger, but what if

1. We dont have a mouse over image in case of single image
2. We have multiple images in case of multiple images.

What i have achieved to do is pretty much basic stuff, which i didnt put in here before.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">            
    <Setter Property="Source" Value="Resources\2.png" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <!-- Hover image -->
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="Resources\3.png"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Now what probablly need to do is add dynanic source but thing i am confused about is how can i add conditional trigger and have different behavior depending on the source.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, i have achieved this by creating a list of BitmapImage, and adding all image(s) to the list. Then i override OnMouseEnter and OnMouseLeave.

OnMouseEnter i started a timer if there are multiple images in the list. And on timer elapsed i updated the image source with the next image in the list.

When OnMouseLeave event occurs i reset the image source with the image at zero index of the list. Which is the main image.

I use INotifyPropertyChanged for binding image source with the property.